# Testing a function which uses fmt.Scanf() in Go

Tags: go

I want to write test for function which includes a call to `fmt.Scanf()`, but I am having problem in passing the **required parameter** to function.

Is there a better way to do this or I need to **mock** `fmt.Scanf()`

Function to be tested is given here:
https://github.com/apsdehal/Konsoole/blob/master/parser.go#L28

```
// Initializes the network interface by finding all the available devices
// displays them to user and finally selects one of them as per the user
func Init() *pcap.Pcap {
    devices, err := pcap.Findalldevs()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(errWriter, "[-] Error, pcap failed to iniaitilize")
    }

    if len(devices) == 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(errWriter, "[-] No devices found, quitting!")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Select one of the devices:")
    var i int = 1
    for _, x := range devices {
        fmt.Println(i, x.Name)
        i++
    }

    var index int

    fmt.Scanf("%d", &index)

    handle, err := pcap.Openlive(devices[index-1].Name, 65535, true, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(errWriter, "Konsoole: %s\n", err)
        errWriter.Flush()
    }
    return handle
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's theoretically possible to change the behavior of `Scanf` by hotswapping the value of `os.Stdin` with some other `os.File`. I wouldn't particularly recommend it just for testing purposes, though.

A better option would just be to make your `Init` take in an `io.Reader` that you pass to `Fscanf`.

Overall, however, it would likely be better to separate your device initialization code from your input as much as possible. This probably means having a device list returning function and a device opening function. You only need to prompt for selection in live/main code.

Comment: So what you mean exactly is to separate out calls to scanf and other like functions so that we can easily test all other parts.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be best.